# SWRevealViewController close left side view when navigation back button pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I have a front view controller and a slide side view.. On navigation bar back button pressed, I have been poping the viewcontroller, to previous view controller. I want my side view to slide out, if it was open when i press back button.

My code is 
      I have a navigation bar with a back button as :

```
 [navbar.backViewButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtnClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

On back button press:

```
-(void)backBtnClicked{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I know I can add revealtoggle as:

```
-(void)backBtnClicked{
[self.revealViewController revealToggleAnimated:YES];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But this gives me a problem, if the side view was closed previously, it toogles and open it, and that is something i don't want on pressing the back button.

I want something like

```
-(void)backBtnClicked{
 if([self.revealViewController isSideViewAppeared or isSideviewShowing]){     
[self.revealViewController revealToggleAnimated:YES];
}
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Help needed.. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add some more code

Comment: if it is under with Root Controller is an SWL , you need to use , [self.revealViewController revealToggleAnimated:YES];, if your viecontroller is in Navigation stack use [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: I worked out the solution by looking swrevealview delegate methods :) thanks for help though

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer, I was just trying to toogle the sideview appear and disappear as :

```
[self.revealViewController revealToggleAnimated:YES];
```

which was toggling the leftview on and off.. simple solution was

```
-(void)backBtnClicked{


[self.revealViewController rightRevealToggleAnimated:YES];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a bool property that stores whether it's open or closed. In viewWillAppear open or close it based on said property.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `SWRevealViewController` navigation method for pop and push.

Write this code into your back button action method.

```
  UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = (id)revealController.frontViewController;
        if ([frontNavigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[YourViewController class]] )        
          viewwaboutus=[[FlashViewController alloc]init];

            UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewwaboutus];
            [revealController pushFrontViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
        }
```

May be it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

To close the Slide-Menu manually when using SWRevealViewController let's try it: `self.revealViewController().revealToggle(animated: true)`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code at button action.

```
if (self.revealViewController.frontViewPosition == 4){

            [self.revealViewController revealToggleAnimated:YES];
}
```